# Convert string into Date type on Python

Tags: python, string, date, type-conversion

I have this string:

```
'2012-02-10' # (year-month-day)
```

and I need it to be as date type for me to use the date function `isoweekday()`.

Does anyone know how I can convert this string into a date?

Comment: This would help for someone who also needs all date and time:

> datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-10-13 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can do that with [`datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

Example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2012-02-10' , '%Y-%m-%d')
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 10, 0, 0)
>>> _.isoweekday()
5
```

You can find the table with all the `strptime` directive [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

---

To increment by 2 days if `.isweekday() == 6`, you can use [`timedelta()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012-02-11' , '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> if date.isoweekday() == 6:
...     date += datetime.timedelta(days=2)
... 
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 13, 0, 0)
>>> date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')   # if you want a string again
'2012-02-13'
```

Comment: That was exactly what I did:

if datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d").isoweekday() == 6: PONTO_MOVIMENTO = a

Comment: Just one more question... how can I add days to my date? For example, if isoweekdday() == 6, i need to increment the date in 2 days. Have idea how I do that? Thanks again!

Comment: I found out already using timedelta. But thanks!

Comment: @user1072627: Yes `timdelta` is the right tool. Even though you've already found it I added an example anyway. :)

Comment: This converts a string to a datetime.  The OP asked how to convert a string to a date.  If I print your converted datetime I get `2012-02-13 00:00:00` which is not a date and does not match the format specified in `strptime`.

Answer (score 133):

While it seems the question was answered per the OP's request, none of the answers give a good way to get a `datetime.date` object instead of a `datetime.datetime`. So for those searching and finding this thread:

`datetime.date` has no `.strptime` method; use the one on `datetime.datetime` instead and then call `.date()` on it to receive the `datetime.date` object.

Like so:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2014-12-04', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
datetime.date(2014, 12, 4)
```

Comment: This is the real answer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: If I convert the datetime.datetime object to a datetime.date object, the datetime.date object doesn't work with the datetime.timedelta() method.  

Is there a way to do date calculations (such as add or subtract days from a date) if the object is datetime.date?

Answer (score 5):

```
from datetime import datetime

a = datetime.strptime(f, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012-02-10', '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> date.isoweekday()
5
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> year, month, day = map(int, my_date.split('-'))
>>> date_object = datetime(year, month, day)
```

Comment: I used something like this when I needed a datetime.date object, NOT a datetime.datetime object.  Unfortunately, datetime.date does not have a strptime() method.