# Calculate time difference using Python

Tags: python, date, time, gps, difference

I am wondering if there is a way or builtin library available to find the difference in time from two string input.

What I mean is, if I have 2 input strings:

1. '2013-10-05T01:21:07Z'
2. '2013-10-05T01:21:16Z'

how can I can calculate the difference in time and print it as output.

I know it sounds a bit silly but any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: [dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil). Have you tried googling?

Comment: First thing I did! I went through the datetime module and time module but could not find anything useful. I am comparatively new to python.

Comment: related: [How to parse ISO formatted date in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/4279)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1345827/608639)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parsing your strings using `strptime()`:

```
a = time.strptime('2013-10-05T01:21:07Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
b = time.strptime('2013-10-05T01:21:16Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

This will parse the given time strings as local times (setting daylight savings (DST) to automatic), and the results are time structs.  These still reflect whether DST was explicitly off (0), on (1), or implicitly automatic (-1).  Convert these to a float (seconds since 1970-01-01):

```
a = time.mktime(a)
b = time.mktime(b)
```

Then compute the difference (in seconds):

```
d = b - a
```

And convert them to days/hours/minutes/seconds:

```
days = int(d) / 86400
hours = int(d) / 3600 % 24
minutes = int(d) / 60 % 60
seconds = int(d) % 60
```

The last block only works properly for positive differences, so be careful not to swap the `a` and `b` ;-)

But @J.F.Sebastian correctly pointed out that this might not be what you intended.  It seems from the notation that your strings describe a UTC time, not a local time.  For mere time differences this is relevant in case your time spans over a DST switch.  In this case it would of course result in a time difference one hour too great or one hour too small (because UTC is always without DST).

To avoid this, you can set the DST flag from automatic (-1) to a fixed value (e. g. 0 for off) and use these values:

```
a = time.mktime(a[:-1] + (0,))  # switch DST to off
b = time.mktime(b[:-1] + (0,))
```

Or, also as @J.F.Sebastian pointed out, you could forget about the `time` module and instead use `datetime.datetime` which is unaware of the DST aspect:

```
a = datetime.datetime.strptime('2013-10-05T01:21:07Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
b = datetime.datetime.strptime('2013-10-05T01:21:16Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

Then the results are `datetime` objects which can be subtracted directly to get a `timedelta` object which represents such a time difference as you want it.  Printing it will result in sth like `0:00:05` which might well be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: the input is UTC time. Use `calendar.timegm()` instead of `time.mktime()` (otherwise there is 50% chance of an error during  DST transitions). Or *better* use `datetime.strptime()` instead of `time.strptime()`.

Comment: the point is: your answer may return a **wrong** result for some input due to the `time.mktime()` usage and you can avoid it completely using `calendar.timegm()`.

Comment: take any two points in time that when interpreted as local time have *different* utc offsets e.g., `time.mktime()`-based code returns wrong result if your local timezone is America/New_York for `2015-11-01T00:00:00Z` and `2015-11-01T06:00:00Z` input.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I rewrote parts of my answer.

Comment: It is still wrong. Try `2014-10-26T00:00:00Z` and `2014-10-26T06:00:00Z` with Europe/Moscow timezone. Don't use `time.mktime()` with UTC time. Drop `time.mktime()` completely. Use `timegm()` (or `datetime` if you don't need to support leap seconds) instead as I've suggested in the first comment

Comment: I can reproduce what you point out for Moscow.  Wow this is strange, and up to now I found nothing on the Internet about this effect, neither could I reproduce it with DST switches here in Germany.  What is causing `mktime()` to behave this way?  Why isn't `tm_isdst` effecting the outcome according to its documentation (which only says that a value of 0 lets `mktime` assume DST is off for this date).  And why is this effecting Moscow TZ but not Berlin TZ?  Do you have some documentation you can link which describes this?

Comment: It's a great answer, as I'm limited to Python 2.5 in a project.

Answer (score 8):

You seem to be using an ISO 8601 formatted [dateTime](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77049.html). This format is used in many places, including the GPS eXchange Format.

```
[-]CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]
```

### Using datetime:

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-10-05T01:21:07Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
b = datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-10-05T01:21:16Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
c = b - a
print(c)
```

**Advantages:**

- Built-in to Python Standard Library
- Object-oriented interface

**Disadvantages:**

- Need to manually handle other valid ISO 8601 representations such as '2013-10-05T01:21:16+00:00'
- Throws exception for leap seconds such as '2012-06-30T23:59:60Z'

### Using python-dateutil:

```
import dateutil.parser
a = dateutil.parser.parse("2013-10-05T01:21:07Z")
b = dateutil.parser.parse("2013-10-05T01:21:16Z")
c = b - a
print(c)
```

**Advantages:**

- Automagically handles pretty much any time format

**Disadvantages:**

- Needs python-dateutil library (pip install python-dateutil)
- Throws exception for leap seconds such as '2012-06-30T23:59:60Z'

### Using time.strptime and time.mktime as suggested by [Alfe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23886181/1703216)

**Advantages:**

- Built-in to Python Standard Library
- Can parse leap seconds such as '2012-06-30T23:59:60Z'

**Disadvantages:**

- Need to manually handle other valid ISO 8601 representations such as '2013-10-05T01:21:16+00:00'
- Loss of one leap second between '2012-06-30T23:59:60Z' and '2012-07-01T00:00:00Z' (unavoidable without knowing when leap seconds will next occur)

Comment: you can [combine `datetime` (to get the difference) + `time.strptime` (to handle leap seconds)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21029510/4279)

Answer (score -2):

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.now()
b = datetime.datetime.now()
c = b - a
datetime.timedelta(0, 8, 562000)
divmod(c.days * 86400 + c.seconds, 60)
```

Original Answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python)

Comment: And parsing date from string?

Comment: This is not what OP asked for!

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504356/convert-string-into-date-type-on-python

Comment: Actually I have 2 gps track points in a comma separated format of Elevation in meters, Date and Time, TrackPointId, Lattitude in degrees, Longitude in degrees.

1) 861.1,2013-10-05T01:21:28Z,3,13.348647,77.686088
2) 867,2013-10-05T01:29:03Z,4,13.34732,77.682364
I want to calculate the time difference in these two track points

Comment: then you have to use relative timedelta which will be easier one for finding datetime difference

Comment: @Prince , so solving Codestorm contest , q4 :)

Comment: I would be thankful if you could give me an example here with one of the track points.

Comment: Yes, everything is done except for the time difference. I can't find a way to get the difference :(