# How to find the timestamp difference between two files

Tags: python, linux, timestamp

When I execute `ll` command I get the timestamps:

```
-rw-rw-r--+ 1    4167 May  5 17:19 file A    
-rw-rw-r--+ 1    2721 May  4 17:08 file B
```

I want the difference between timestamps of A and B

I tried this:

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(getmtime(file)).strftime('%h %m %s'))
```

It gives

```
May 05 1557032395
May 04 1557084082
```

Please help me get the time difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1345827/608639), [Calculate time difference using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23885390/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need.

```
import os
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("file A")) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("file A")))
```

You can subtract 2 datetime objects to get the difference.