# Sorting Strings of Dates in Python, Preferably Without Using Date Objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

So, I have a *list of strings* that are all formatted in *Month* *DayNumber*, like

```
['March 1', 'March 9', 'April 14', 'March 12']
```

I need to sort the list so all the dates are in the order they would be in a calendar. Any tips? Is there a built-in method that might be able to help me, or should I design a custom sort using a lambda?

Comment: Other than the `key` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to review this question: [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

After parsing you could sort by date based on the values obtained from parsing string into datetime objects (which are sortable).

Comment: I had done that, and had the code (sorted(testing, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%Y-%d'))), but it did not work so I went back to the drawing board.

Comment: are you sure `%Y` should have been there? I would just use `'%B %d'` (where `%B` is the full month name in the current locale). It worked for me like a charm on the data you provided.

Comment: my data was different when I wrote that orginally, my bad. The issue is that the data is getting passed as a list, not a string, and throwing an error. I'll look into it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also leverage the calendar module:

```
from calendar import month_name
months = list(month_name)

def parser (text):
    """Parses 'englishmonthname_whitespace_day-number' into string 'monthNR.dayNr'. 
    Will pad a zero to allow for string based sorting."""  
    try:
        month,day = text.split()
        monthAsIdx = months.index(month.strip())
        return '{:02d}.{:02d}'.format(monthAsIdx,int(day)) # return index in list.days
    except (ValueError, IndexError): # ValueError if not enough elements in string,
                                     # IndexError if not in list of month names
        return "99.99" # put last - all errors are put last w/o specific reordering

dates = ['TooFew', 'EnoughBut NotInList', 'March 1', 'March 9', 'April 14', 'March 12'] 

for n in dates:
    print(parser(n))


sortedDates = sorted(dates, key=lambda x: parser(x))

print(sortedDates)
```

Output:

```
# result of parser()
99.99
99.99
03.01
03.09
04.14
03.12

# sorted by key/lambda
['March 1', 'March 9', 'March 12', 'April 14', 'TooFew', 'EnoughBut NotInList']
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `numpy.argsort` combined with `datetime` library.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

lst = ['March 1', 'March 9', 'April 14', 'March 12']

arr = np.array(lst)
res = arr[np.argsort([datetime.strptime(i+' 2018', '%B %d %Y') for i in lst])].tolist()
```

Result:

```
['March 1', 'March 9', 'March 12', 'April 14']
```

This is possible because, internally, dates are just numeric data. In this case, we attach an arbitrary year 2018 to create `datetime` objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas module. 
Install it with pip.

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ['March 1', 'March 9', 'April 14', 'March 12']

df = pd.DataFrame(dates)
df = pd.to_datetime(df[0], format="%B %d")

df=df.sort_values() 

print (df)
```

This datetime format can be very useful like for example if you want the day or the month of an element of the list just do:

```
df.month
df.day
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possibilities**:

- Use a dictionary and use `key/value`
- Use string matching (regex)
- Many more ...

Or **google** and use any of these:

- [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)
- [Convert string into Date type on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504356/convert-string-into-date-type-on-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [how to convert a string date into datetime format in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068269/how-to-convert-a-string-date-into-datetime-format-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

To provide **a** possible solution:

```
Input_list = [{'month':'March', 'day':30}, {'month':'March', 'day':10}]

newlist = sorted(Input_list, key=lambda k: k['month'])
```